# How can I log each request/response using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, debugging, afnetworking-2, alamofire

Is there a way to log each request / response using Alamofire (something similar to AFNetworkActivityLogger) ?

I am aware of Printable, DebugPrintable and Output (cURL) but they are not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 66):

There's a sweet little pod for this: https://github.com/konkab/AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger

Add this to your podfile:

```
pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0'
```

In your AppDelegate:

```
import AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger
```

Then in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, add this:

```
NetworkActivityLogger.shared.level = .debug
NetworkActivityLogger.shared.startLogging()
```

EDIT:
I've actually encountered crashes with this in production. To be on the safe side, use "build flags" to only use this in debug, something like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    NetworkActivityLogger.shared.level = .debug
    NetworkActivityLogger.shared.startLogging()
#endif
```

Comment: This is the best option since it does not requiring any changes to existing code.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Comment: Small update needed to support Swift 5 / Xcode 11, but works perfectly!

Comment: @vedrano what' that?

Comment: @VarunRaj nothing special, just a simple adjustment to latest Swift syntax.

Answer (score 49):

Something like this might be what you were looking for:

```
extension Request {
   public func debugLog() -> Self {
      #if DEBUG
         debugPrint(self)
      #endif
      return self
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .debugLog()
         .response {…}
```

If you want to print all responses, you could write your own response method, similar to the responseObject() method at the top of this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87595/intermediate-alamofire-tutorial

[Update: added below per the request from @trauzti.]

Here's how one might do the responseObject() approach in order to print output on *every* request.

Caveat lector: I haven't personally tested this code, and would probably make different choices in production. This simply shows how the Wenderlich tutorial code can include debug logging. Also note: since the tutorial is pre-Swift 2.0, I've used the old println() instead of print().

```
@objc public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
  init(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
  public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    let serializer: Serializer = { (request, response, data) in

      #if DEBUG
         println("Request: \(request.URL)")
      #endif

      let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
      let (JSON: AnyObject?, serializationError) = JSONSerializer(request, response, data)
      if response != nil && JSON != nil {
        #if DEBUG
           println("Response:")
           debugPrint(JSON)
        #endif

        return (T(response: response!, representation: JSON!), nil)
      } else {
        #if DEBUG
           println("Failed Serialization:")
           debugPrint(serializationError)
        #endif

        return (nil, serializationError)
      }
    }

    return response(serializer: serializer, completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) in
      completionHandler(request, response, object as? T, error)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Could you post the code you have in mind for the responseObject extension?

Comment: Haven't got time to revisit this right now, @MatthieuRiegler. Care to provide a v3-compatible writeup? :)

Comment: @clozach can we make it call debugLog automatically when request is called?

Comment: @clozach can we stop the request if some condition met in debugLog(), I tried request.cancel(), but still it goes the the request with result failure

Comment: @vinbhai4u Sorry, not sure…I'm not currently using any of this in production code.

Comment: @clozach I am trying to use your code, but whats Serializer? is it some kind of JSON parser or something?

Comment: @vinbhai4u Sorry again. Been out of town, and I still don't have any good info for you…. It looks like the raywenderlich tutorial has been updated since I posted this answer, so I have no reference for the code above. Maybe try ResponseSerializer instead of Serializer???

Answer (score 24):

Since Alamofire 5, the easiest way is to define an [`EventMonitor`](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Protocols/EventMonitor.html) subclass:

```
final class AlamofireLogger: EventMonitor {
    func requestDidResume(_ request: Request) {
        let body = request.request.flatMap { $0.httpBody.map { String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self) } } ?? "None"
        let message = """
        ⚡️ Request Started: \(request)
        ⚡️ Body Data: \(body)
        """
        NSLog(message)
    }

    func request<Value>(_ request: DataRequest, didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value>) {
        NSLog("⚡️ Response Received: \(response.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Then use it on your [session](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/Classes/Session.html):

```
let session = Session(eventMonitors: [ AlamofireLogger() ])
```

This sample code was adapted from https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2867#issuecomment-509662892

Comment: In Alamofire 5.0.0 I had to replace "DataResponse" by "AFDataResponse"

Comment: what if I am using 'AF.request' ?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
@LMaker AF is referencing the Alamofire session. you would then use session.request instead.

Comment: I am not sure why but the only callback I am getting is requestDidResume and the rest not firing up. In addition I've also tried using ClosureEventMonitor and getting the same result.

Answer (score 11):

Timberjack is what you are looking.
Timberjack is a simple, unintrusive network activity logger. Log every request your app makes, or limit to only those using a certain NSURLSession if you’d prefer. It also works with Alamofire, if that’s your thing.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/Timberjack

usage:

```
import Alamofire
import Timberjack

class HTTPManager: Alamofire.Manager {
static let sharedManager: HTTPManager = {
    let configuration = Timberjack.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let manager = HTTPManager(configuration: configuration)
    return manager
}()
}
```

Comment: How do you limit it to an NSURLSession?

Comment: It works but for some reason, app became way too much slow when Timberjack is active and not all requests are tracked automatically. Maybe that's by-design.

Answer (score 7):

in Alamofire 5 URLRequest is created asynchronously which means

```
extension Request {
 public func debugLog() -> Self {
  #if DEBUG
     debugPrint(self)
  #endif
  return self
  }
}
```

is not the best solution anymore. instead, calling `cURLDescription` is recommend as below:

```
let request = AF.request(<Your request>))
request.cURLDescription { (curl) in
   print("CURL \(curl)")
}
request.responseJSON { response in
   //Do something with your response...
}
```

or

```
extension Request {
public func debugLog() -> Self {
    #if DEBUG
    cURLDescription(calling: { (curl) in
        debugPrint("=======================================")
        print(curl)
        debugPrint("=======================================")
    })
    #endif
    return self
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to above answer
for Alamofire 4.0+ Swift 3

```
extension DataRequest {        
        public func LogRequest() -> Self {
        //Your logic for logging
        return self
    }
}
```

When Requesting

```
Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .LogRequest()
            .responseJSON { response in
            //Do your thing
            }
```

If you want to cancel the request in any case(which was something I wanted) you can `self.cancel()` anywhere before you return self

Answer (score 2):

In Alamofire 5.0.0 I used the answer based on:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2867#issuecomment-509662892
but I had to replace DataResponse by AFDataResponse. For example:

```
import Alamofire

final class AlamofireLogger: EventMonitor {

    func requestDidResume(_ request: Request) {

        let allHeaders = request.request.flatMap { $0.allHTTPHeaderFields.map { $0.description } } ?? "None"
        let headers = """
        ⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Request Started: \(request)
        ⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Headers: \(allHeaders)
        """
        NSLog(headers)


        let body = request.request.flatMap { $0.httpBody.map { String(decoding: $0, as: UTF8.self) } } ?? "None"
        let message = """
        ⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Request Started: \(request)
        ⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Body Data: \(body)
        """
        NSLog(message)
    }

    func request<Value>(_ request: DataRequest, didParseResponse response: AFDataResponse<Value>) {

        NSLog("⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Response Received: \(response.debugDescription)")
        NSLog("⚡️⚡️⚡️⚡️ Response All Headers: \(String(describing: response.response?.allHeaderFields))")
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in the following way:

```
let session = Session(eventMonitors: [ AlamofireLogger() ])
```

As it has explained by 0xced in an aforementioned post.

Comment: It's not logging all the data, my body is getting trimmed. Do not use `NSLog`.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION FOR SWIFT 3.0+**

For Printing Request parameter and headers:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<T>) in
                self.pendingRequests.removeValue(forKey: endPoint)
                completion!(response)

                if(NetworkConfig.loggingEnable) {
                    debugPrint("************* printing REQUEST parameter and Headers *************")
                    debugPrint("RESPONSE : \(response.debugDescription)")
                }
        }.responseDebugPrint()
```

**For Printing Response** . use below extension .

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

extension Alamofire.DataRequest {
    func responseDebugPrint() -> Self {
        if NetworkConfig.loggingEnable {

            return responseJSON() {
                response in
                if let  JSON = response.result.value,
                    let JSONData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSON, options: .prettyPrinted),
                    let prettyString = NSString(data: JSONData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    print(prettyString)
                } else if let error = response.result.error {
                    print("Error Debug Print: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Small gist for you : 
https://gist.github.com/manishpathak99/348f2eb0167c0ff6e12ecd667612bc9b/edit

Answer (score 0):

In Alamofire 5 and above you can get `curl` request details by the below code:

```
request.cURLDescription(calling: { (curl) in
    print(curl)
})
```

And response/error data:

```
request.responseDecodable { (response:AFDataResponse<T>) in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                
                var responseMessage : String?
                
                if let data = response.data {
                    let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    responseMessage = String(describing: json)
                }
                
                print(responseMessage)
                
                break;
                
            case .failure(let error):
                
                var message : String?
                
                if let data = response.data {
                    let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    message = String(describing: json)
                }
                
                print(message)
                
                break
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire provides a powerful way to gain insight into all the internal events via the `EventMonitor` protocol. `EventMonitor` includes several Alamofire events such as `URLSessionDelegate` request events. This makes `EventMonitor` ideal for logging events.

```swift
import Alamofire

class NetworkLogger: EventMonitor {
  
  let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.company.project.networklogger")
  
  func requestDidFinish(_ request: Request) {
    print(request.description)
  }
  
  func request<Value>(
    _ request: DataRequest,
    didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value, AFError>
  ) {
    guard let data = response.data else {
      return
    }
    if let json = try? JSONSerialization
      .jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
        print(json)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://www.raywenderlich.com/11668143-alamofire-tutorial-for-ios-advanced-usage#toc-anchor-004